# Calling DDOT function in BLAS library

Tags: c, blas

I am calling a BLAS function in my code by including the BLAS library, and my code apparently is faulty somehow, as the compiler spits out the error: *"ddot was not declared in this scope."*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <blas.h>

int main()
{
        double  m[10],n[10];
        int i;
        int result;

        printf("Enter the elements into first vector.\n");
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("%lf",&m[i]);

        printf("Enter the elements into second vector.\n");
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("%lf",&n[i]);

        result = ddot(m,n);
        printf("The result is %d\n",result);

        return 0;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this code properly?

Comment: It would appear that `ddot` is not declared in `<blas.h>`, contrary to your assumption.  Did you look for it in the header?

Comment: But blas library has the inbuilt function.

Comment: Search for `ddot` in the header, and report back with what you find.

Comment: Check this link. http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/linalg/Blas.html

Comment: That's not the header.  I mean search for `ddot` in the actual header file `blas.h` that is being included by your compiler.

Comment: How can I see the header file? I tried going to that path http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html but nothing is visible for me.

Comment: If you're using gcc, you have two simple options: either pass the `-v` flag which will cause the compiler to list the search paths for headers (the header will be in one of those directories), or pass `-E` which will print out the fully preprocessed source, which will include any declarations in the headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling from C, the function name must either be `cblas_ddot()` (C calling conventions) or `ddot_` (fortran calling conventions; note the trailing underscore.)

You are missing some function arguments.  Try

```
result = cblas_ddot(10, m, 1, n, 1);
```

or equivalently

```
int len = 10, incm = 1, incn = 1;
// ...
result = ddot_(&len, m, &incm, n, &incn);
```

Also, ddot returns a double but you are assigning the result to an int.