# "undefined reference to 'cblas_ddot'" when using cblas library

Tags: c, blas

I was testing the cblas ddot, and the code I used is from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470799/calling-ddot-function-in-blas-library) and I fixed it as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cblas.h>

int main()
{
    double  m[10],n[10];
    int i;
    int result;

    printf("Enter the elements into first vector.\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("%lf",&m[i]);

    printf("Enter the elements into second vector.\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("%lf",&n[i]);

    result = cblas_ddot(10, m, 1, n, 1);
    printf("The result is %d\n",result);

    return 0;
}
```

Then when I compiled it, it turned out to be:

```
/tmp/ccJIpqKH.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the cblas file in `/usr/include/cblas.h`, and noticed there is

```
double cblas_ddot(const int N, const double *X, const int incX,
              const double *Y, const int incY);
```

I don't know where it is going wrong. Why does the compiler said the "cblas_ddot" is undefined reference?

Comment: What does your GCC command line, or `Makefile` look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just include the header - that only tells the compiler that the functions exist *somewhere*. You need to tell the linker to link against the cblas library.

Assuming you have a `libcblas.a` file, you can tell GCC about it with `-lcblas`.

The web site for GNU Scientific Library tells you how to do this:

- [2.2 Compiling and Linking](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Compiling-and-Linking.html#Compiling-and-Linking)

Comment: I tried `gcc -Wall -I/usr/include -c test.c` and it works. But then I executed `gcc test.o -o test`, it still was `undefined reference to 'cblas_ddot'`.

Comment: The first invokation of `gcc` is just compiling `test.c` to `test.o`. The library is not used at all yet. If you run [`readelf -s test.o`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readelf+1), you will see the unresolved symbol `cblas_ddot`.
Your second invokation of `gcc` is just linking `test.o` against `libc` and creating the final output executable. It is here that you need to specify linking against the cblas library.

Comment: I got it. Then I tried the method [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html#Linking-programs-with-the-library), there is still an error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas`.

Comment: Have you installed the library? `-l` will look in the standard directories, which does not include the current directory.

Comment: `find /lib* /usr/lib* -name lib*.a`

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems there is no lcblas or anything looked like it. Maybe the library hasn't been installed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was just solved. The reason is that I made a mistake when inputed the link path. Thanks for [Jonathon Reinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119527/jonathon-reinhart)'s answers, they are really helpful when learning how to code in linux.

The compile commands are:

```
gcc -c test.c
gcc -L/usr/lib64 test.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Where "/usr/lib64" is the correct link path.