# Shark Machine Learning library: undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'

Tags: c++, linux, machine-learning

I'm using Shark-3.0.0 machine learning library.

When compiling and linking Shark libraries, I get an error relating to a library Shark is using: cblas

CMA.cpp:(.text+0x1687): undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'll be thankful for some help,
Peleg

Comment: Seems like Shark source code was compiled against the library, but it is missing on linker command-line.

Comment: This seems to be the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507841/undefined-reference-to-cblas-ddot-when-using-cblas-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["undefined reference to 'cblas\_ddot'" when using cblas library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507841/undefined-reference-to-cblas-ddot-when-using-cblas-library)

Answer (score 1):

The linker can not find a the object code for the function named `cblas_ddot`

This is most likely because you are lacking a library.

What OS are you using? If you are using something like Ubuntu you can most likely install it via `apt-get`.

If you have the library you may need to link against with the `-lcblas` command line option.